# Base url issues and subdirectories

Tags: uri

I have a drupal site at http://example.com and a development version of the same site at http://another.example.com/subdir. When I'm working on the development version, content that references /sites/default/files/ - such as images - doesn't work because it needs to include the '/subdir' part of the path. Setting `$base_url` doesn't work because that uses the `BASE` element's `href` attribute which doesn't affect urls beginning `/` if the `href` includes a subdirectory.

What's the best way of including the subdir in the image references? Do I need to resort to a server rewrite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you can do here in order to try and make you site more portable.

In your templates:

- Always use `l()` for *all* links (even JavaScript links)
- If you need to reference an image in the theme use:

  ```
  <img src="<?php echo $base_path . drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename'); ?>/logo.png" />
  ```

In your content:

- You do not really have a way in order to preserve uploaded content URL's unless using some form of [file manager](http://drupal.org/project/webfm) which do not create absolute links, but much rather links that get sent to drupal that redirect to the file
- If the above is not going to work for you then a modification of the rewrite rules for the drupal site sitting under the subdir is required to basically rewrite all URLs requested that start with sites/default/files/(.*) rewritten to subdir/sites/default/files/$1

And the apache mod_rewrite rule may look like the following.

```
# Redirect all files requests to a subdir
RewriteRule ^/?sites/default/files/(.*) /subdir/sites/default/files/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yup - the rewrite turned out to be the best way of doing this - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The module [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) can help you with this.

Comment: Indeed, this is pretty much exactly the use case I wrote it for. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you have any flexibility over the domain of development site at all, we've found that everything just works if you use:

example.com -> production

dev.example.com -> development

Your sites dir will work as /sites/example.com in both cases.  You just need to modify your base_url to match the domain.