# $base_url set to an external domain causes problems when logging in

Tags: configuration, uri

I am developing a conference site with Drupal 7. The site is hosted at domain1.com. The conference is covered by another organization, and they require the conference page to be accessible from their own domain, something like organization.com/conference2014.
Fortunately, Drupal has the `$base_url` variable and the site is accessible from organization.com/conference2014.

My problem is when I want to access administration interface of Drupal from organization.com/conference2014?q=user/login. After I enter my credentials, Drupal redirects me to the organization.com site which is administrated by the organization administrator. When I access again organization.com/conference2014, it still asks me for the password.

What I need to achieve is, after entering the credentials, being redirected to organization.com/conference2014, and being to perform any administration task.

Do you have any idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base url issues and subdirectories](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/499/base-url-issues-and-subdirectories)

Comment: No, the supposed duplicate question is asking about something different. In that question, the problem is generating links that works when migrating a site from the development site to the production site. This question is not about a site that is migrated, but a site that is available under two domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can set action on after login user.

And that action could trigger through set a perticular trigger.

please use these url to solve this issue in your site.

1. www.example.com/admin/config/system/actions
2. www.example.com/admin/structure/trigger/user

Hope this works for you.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Sanjay, interesting solution. I have set the redirect url action after user logs in. However, the problem is when the user gets redirected I can only see the normal version of the site without administration options - any idea what has to be set up? thanks a lot, Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting $cookie_domain to example1.com (The domain you're hosting the website on, not the primary access domain of the conference host). And logging in through that domain?

See:
https://drupal.org/node/1096962